# what is front end recursion?

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion

I have seen the term as opposed to tail end recursion and I was wondering what the difference between the two was. So basically **What is Front End Recursion?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is tail-recursion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Front end recursion is when you make the recursive call first in the method, while tail end recursion is when you make the recursive call last in the method.

Example of front end recursion:

```
void Show(int num) {
  if (num > 0) {
    Show(num - 1);
  }
  Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

Result of `Show(3);`:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Example of tail end recursion:

```
void Show(int num) {
  Console.WriteLine(num);
  if (num > 0) {
    Show(num - 1);
  }
}
```

Result of `Show(3);`:

```
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: See also recursive tree traversal algorithms for another example : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal